# Angular factories : how do I return a function that operates on $scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factories

I've had a function that works fine included with controllers individually to modify data for $scope but when I try to add it to scope with an injected factory instead...it fails to run. Other data returned by same factory returns fine.

Here is original function:

```
  $scope.sortByRooms = function () {
                    var amount = 0;
                    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.customers.length; i++) {
                        amount += $scope.customers[i].area * $scope.customers[i].price;
                    }
                    if (amount < 100 && amount > 0) {
                        $scope.alertBadPrice = true;
                        $scope.contact.totalQuote = amount;
                        return amount;
                    } else {
                        $scope.contact.totalQuote = amount;
                        $scope.alertBadPrice = false;
                        return amount;
                    }
                };
```

However returning as a factory object like this......

```
app.controller('blahblah', [$scope, factoryObject, function($scope, factoryObject) { 
    $scope.customers = factoryObject.list();
    $scope.sortByRooms = factoryObject.sortByRooms();
```

fails to work. The other returned data objects like customers work fine, but not my function.

Should I instead return my function like this?

```
sortByRooms = function (obj, obj1, obj3) {
                var amount = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                    amount += obj[i].area * obj[i].price;
                }
                if (amount < 100 && amount > 0) {
                    obj1 = true;
                    obj3.totalQuote = amount;
                    return amount;
                } else {
                    obj1 = false;
 obj3.totalQuote = amount;

                    return amount;
                }
            };
```

or should I keep the original function the same but inject scope into the factory object like so:

```
gapp.factory('factoryObj',[ $scope, function ($scope) {....}
```

Comment: in your controller you set a function to sortByRooms which means you can use it as a function but in second version u set sortByRooms to return of function. They are not same...

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, correcting now.

Comment: factories cannot interact with `$scope`.  `$scope` is exclusively for two way binding between controllers and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Factories should not use `$scope` ever. It looks like you really need to separate your work out into smaller functions. The first one looks like a utility function that calculates a total based on customer info:

```
totalAmount = function(customers){
    var amount = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<customers.length; i++){
        amount += customers[i].area * customers[i].price;
    }
    return amount;
};
```

Then you should have other functions that make decisions about what to do with that amount. Also why did you name the function `sortByRooms`, when no sorting takes place?

Comment: There is a live quote cart and customer price = number of rooms x stored table price.

Comment: According to your function they are always the same value.